# Linked list implementations difference

Tags: c

For the following linked list declaration,

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct list
{
   int val;
   struct list *next;
} list;


void destroy (list *l)
{
    if (l)
    {
        destroy (l->next);
        free (l);
    }
}
```

why does the following main work

```
int main()
{
    list *test;
    list *ptr1, *ptr2;
    int i;
    test = malloc (sizeof (list));
    test->val = 0;
    ptr2 = test;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        ptr1 = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
        ptr1->val = i;
        ptr2->next = ptr1;
        ptr2 = ptr1;
    }
    ptr1 = test;
    while (ptr1)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", ptr1->val);
        ptr1 = ptr1->next ;
    }
    destroy (test);
    return 0;
}
```

while this one doesn't even create a list (it only makes one node)?

```
int main()
{
    list *test;
    list *ptr;
    int i;
    test = malloc (sizeof (list));
    test->val = 0;
    ptr = test->next;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        ptr = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
        ptr->val = i;
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
    ptr = test;
    while (ptr)
    {
        printf ("%d\n", ptr->val);
        ptr = ptr->next ;
    }
    destroy (test);
    return 0;
}
```

Don't they use the same logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
ptr = test->next;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    ptr = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
    ptr->val = i;
    ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

starts by taking a copy of `test->next` but never assigns anything to `test->next` itself.  A list starting from `test` therefore only has a single item.  Worse, that item has an uninitialised `next` pointer so code that tries to iterate over the list will almost certainly crash.

As hinted at in the other answers, this pattern is repeated for each newly allocated node.

In answer to your comment, the best way to make the second function work is to make it more like the first (working) version.  I've renamed the variables in it to try to make it clearer

```
list *head;
list *next, *curr;
int i;
head = malloc (sizeof(*head));
head->val = 0;
curr= head;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    next = malloc (sizeof(*next));
    next->val = i;
    curr->next = next;
    curr= next;
}
curr= head;
```

Comment: how can i change the second main so that it'll work? (assuming that i won't come to the first main)

Comment: @KudayarPirimbaev I've updated my answer to cover this.  Without meaning to be glib, you need to make your code look more like the working version you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In the second main during

```
ptr = test->next;
```

you are trying to acces test->next withouth allocating memory for it.You can try changing your code as following to get second main working

```
test = malloc (sizeof (list));
    test->val = 0;
    test->next = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
    ptr = test->next;
    for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    {
        ptr->val = i;
    ptr->next = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
        ptr = ptr->next;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like in the first example, which works, `ptr2` is holding the previously created node in the list, so that this can be rewritten

```
last_created_node = test;
for (i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    // create new node
    new_node = (list *) malloc (sizeof (list));
    new_node ->val = i;
    // chain newly created node onto list so far
    // make last created node point to new node
    last_created_node->next = new_node ;
    // last created node is now new node
    last_created_node = new_node ;
}
// terminate the list
last_created_node->next = 0;
```

There is no equivalent of linking a new node onto the chain in the second code sample you give. Also there are problems with unitialised memory as others have commented. Would be good to add the termination condition as shown in the last line of my sample above.